# ClassNotFoundException: com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter cannot be found by mymodule

Tags: liferay, osgi, servlet-filters, liferay-7

I wrote a Liferay 7 module that contains only this class:

```
...

@Component(
        immediate = true,
        property = {
                "servlet-context-name=",
                "servlet-filter-name=myfilter",
                "url-pattern=/*"
        },
        service = Filter.class
)
public class MyFilter extends BaseFilter {
    ...
}
```

It compiles fine, but deploying it on a freshly installed Liferay 7 makes this error appear:

```
STARTED com.liferay.marketplace.deployer_2.0.9 [170]
STARTED mymodule_1.0.0 [668]
[mymodule:97] BundleComponentActivator : Bundle [668] Unexpected failure enabling component holder my.MyFilter
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/liferay/portal/kernel/servlet/BaseFilter
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
[...]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter cannot be found by mymodule_1.0.0
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:444)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:357)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:349)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 48 more
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my module's `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    compileOnly group: "biz.aQute.bnd", name: "biz.aQute.bndlib", version: "3.1.0"
    compileOnly group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.osgi.util", version: "3.0.0"
    compileOnly group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.portal.spring.extender", version: "2.0.0"
    compileOnly group: "com.liferay.portal", name: "com.liferay.portal.kernel", version: "2.0.0"
    compileOnly group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.portal.security.audit.api", version: "2.0.0"
    compileOnly group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.portal.configuration.metatype", version: "2.0.0"
    compileOnly group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.document.library.web", version: "1.0.10"
    compileOnly group: "org.osgi", name: "org.osgi.compendium", version: "5.0.0"
    compileOnly group: "javax.portlet", name: "portlet-api", version: "2.0"
    compileOnly group: "javax.servlet", name: "servlet-api", version: "2.5"
    compileOnly group: "org.osgi", name:"org.osgi.service.component.annotations", version:"1.3.0"
}
```

Comment: Assuming you're using Liferay Workspace/gradle: What are your declared dependencies for this project? compileOnly?

Comment: @OlafKock: I added my `build.gradle`.

Comment: You can try adding the Import-Package as Neil recommended to the bnd.bnd file and see if it works. I found that sometimes I had to add dependencies to the build.gradle and bnd.bnd file and sometimes only to one of these files for different kind of Liferay module projects. I am not sure why yet. If the error still persists, play with using the "compile group:" in build.gradle file. Good luck. I know I went through similar issues for my modules.

Answer (score 0):

This error means that your bundle should import the package `com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet`.

OSGi bundles can only load from packages that they either directly contain or have explicitly imported using the `Import-Package` manifest header.

Answer (score 0):

I think your jar Manifest is missing the package import for `com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet`.

How do you create your bundle?

The typical error that leads to this is to manually configure imported packages and miss the `,*` to enable that bnd automatically analyzes the imports.